# PHP header location function not working in form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to make a registration form for my website. I'm using the code below. All the error handlers work fine since it's adding the users into my database. I've trid to add ob_start. I removed all white spaces using a plugin for sublime text. I tried to use javascript instead of php (top.window). I also tried to use full url instead of just directories. But when I click submit it doesnt redirect me to the address I put after Location. When I click the button it takes me to this php file but doesnt redirect me back to the registration page which is a seperate file(I know there are a lot of similar questions that have been asked but they dont seem to work for my situation).
Does anyone know how to fix that?

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

include_once 'db.php';

$uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);

//error handlers
//Check for empty fields
if (empty($uid) || empty($pwd) || empty($email)) {

    header("Location : /login/register.php?signup=empty");
    exit();

} else{

    //Check if input characters are valid
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $uid)) {

        header('Location: /login/register.php?signup=invalid');
        exit();

    } else {

        //Check if email is valid
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            header('Location : /login/register.php?signup=email');
            exit();
        } else {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid='$uid'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                header('Location : /login/register.php?signup=usertaken');
            exit();
            } else {
                //Hashing the password
                $hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                //Insert the user into the databse
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_uid, user_pwd, user_email) VALUES ('$uid', '$hashedPwd', '$email');";
                mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                header('Location : /login/register.php?signup=success');
                exit();
            }
        }



    }

}

} else {
    header('Location : /login/register.php');
    exit();
}
```

**Solved - Removing space after "location" answer by Nigel Ren**

Comment: just add domain name also this type uy can't locate ur domain

Comment: Any error message? Like header already sent or something similar

Comment: check if there are trailing spaces in "db.php"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you don't have a space after location and before the :...

```
header('Location : /login/register.php');
```

should be

```
header('Location: /login/register.php');
```

Comment: @AlanLin can you mark this as the accepted answer if your happy with it (check https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers if your not sure how)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use absolute URI

```
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
header("Location: ".$host."/login/register.php?signup=empty");
```

Answer (score 0):

replace all header to location.assign

```
header('Location : /login/register.php');
```

replace to

```
echo "<script>location.assign('/login/register.php')</script>";
```

after use location assign , maybe problem sol..